# python - UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, ascii

I try to read the dump hex file and convert it to ASCII. What should I do?

````
def file_open():
    text_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/Users/mshalhadhrawi/Desktop", title="select the file")
    text_file = open(text_file,"rb")
    stuff = (binascii.b2a_base64(text_file.read().decode()))
    my_text.insert(END,stuff)```
````

I get error on this line:
`stuff = (binascii.b2a_base64 (text_file.read().decode()))`

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 2: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See about [ask] and how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

`decode("ascii")`

Otherwise Python3 will assume it is Unicode text, and decode it as Unicode glyphs. What you want is ASCII, tell it at the moment to decode.

Also, beware that not all 1-byte values are valid ASCII : it is only defined for the lower half (from `0x00` to `0x7f` included) so if your data contains values in the invalid range (from `0x80` to `0xff`) you will get a similar error. In that case, it is just not ASCII data so you should not try to decode it as such. But you can specify an optional [`codec error handler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers) to handle such issues, like that :

```py
binary_data = b"\x40\xc3"  # the bytes 0x40 then 0xC3
binary_data.decode("ascii")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
binary_data.decode("ascii", errors="backslashreplace")
'@\\xc3'  # the ASCII symbol @ (0x40) then a "backslashreplace"
```

Comment: `stuff = (binascii.b2a_base64(text_file.read().decode("ascii")))`

Comment: `stuff = (binascii.b2a_base64(text_file.read().decode("ascii")))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf3 in position 2: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @MeshalHadhrawi `0xf3` is not a correct ascii value, you can't display your file content as ASCII if it does not contain non-ASCII values. How would you represent `0xf3` as ASCII ? In my answer, I explained how to handle it already, add `errors="backslashreplace"` to the `decode` call. But it has nothing to do with base64, does your file contains base64 data ? In any case, please update your answer providing the file content, it makes answering much easier.